# Android menu is not displaying with toolbar - Only with actionbar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to show a menu. I can show the menu, but only with the ActionBar. But it's not going to toolbar. I tried using a Theme AppCompat without ActionBar, but the toolbar still empty.

**menu_toolbar.xml** - It's correct, it's working on ActionBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        >
  <item
        android:id="@+id/action_call"
        android:title="Call"
        app:showAsAction="always"       
        />

</menu>
```

My manifest with the theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="OrderFoodApp.OrderFoodApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application 
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
  </application>
</manifest>
```

My main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my class (I tried with OnPrepareOptionsMenu too)

```
namespace OrderFoodApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "OrderFoodApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);            
            toolbar.Title = "Hi";
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `OnCreateOptionsMenu` instead of `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` because `OnPrepareOptionsMenu` is for manipulating menu items only so use this

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)  
{  
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_toolbar, menu);  
    return true;  
}
```

instead of this

```
public override bool OnPrepareOptionsMenu(IMenu menu){
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried this, I said it in the post. It doesn't work. :/ I have a project that works and I can't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: @OnScreen follow the answer and try moving `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);` after `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: I tried. It dosn't work. I was using var to find the Toolbar, but now I'm using the class. And I find out that my toolbar is coming null.

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar has to be on the same level as the DrawerLayout. You can make a relative layout to include the Toolbar at top and the DrawerLayout below.

Comment: I tried. I was using var to find the Toolbar, but now I'm using the class. And I find out that my toolbar is coming null.